# Should View objects in Android have a variable assigned to them if that variable is never used?

Tags: android, variables, view

Should View objects (TextViews, EditTexts, etc) have a variable assigned to them in `onCreateView` even if the variable will never be used? Is it acceptable to just assign the object's id to the Fragment using `findViewById` and access the object by using its id instead?

**More detail:**

I have several EditText values that are being initialized like this:

```
EditText role1 = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.role1_edit_text);
EditText role2 = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.role2_edit_text);
// Six other similar entries truncated
```

However, I'm not using the actual variables for `role1` so Android Studio suggests removing the variable and writing it like this:

```
root.findViewById(R.id.role1_edit_text);
root.findViewById(R.id.role2_edit_text);
// Six other similar entries truncated
```

I have never seen Views assigned this way and just happened upon it because I'm referencing the EditText by their ids in my methods like this:

```
// Accessing View objects using view ids
editTextIds = new int[]{R.id.add_location_role1_edit_text, R.id.add_location_role2_edit_text,
            R.id.add_location_role3_edit_text, R.id.add_location_role4_edit_text,
            R.id.add_location_role5_edit_text, R.id.add_location_role6_edit_text,
            R.id.add_location_role7_edit_text, R.id.add_location_title_edit_text};

private boolean allFieldsHaveInput() {
    for (int id : editTextIds) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(id);
        if (isTextEmpty(editText)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have several such methods that use loops to go through all the EditText ids so switching to variables would definitely make the code more verbose. I feel like `EditText editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(id);` might be slightly more expensive computationally, but with roughly eight Views it seems like a small price to pay so I don't have to write the method like this:

```
// Accessing View objects using a variable
private EditText role1, role2, role3, role4, role5, role6, role7, role8;

private boolean allFieldsHaveInput() {
    return !isTextEmpty(role1) && !isTextEmpty(role2) && !isTextEmpty(role3)
             !isTextEmpty(role4) && !isTextEmpty(role5) &&
             !isTextEmpty(role6) && !isTextEmpty(role7) &&
             !isTextEmpty(role8);
}
```

I have never seen View objects assigned without a variable in open source code so I'm a little concerned if removing the variable is a bad idea (especially since I'm planning to put the code up on GitHub).

From a readability standpoint would it be better to just assign variables like `role1` even if the code becomes slightly more verbose?

Comment: this question looks more like a x-y problem. so i would prefer knowing the reason behind your current implementation. if you can tell what exactly you are actually doing. people can give you much better solutions

Comment: Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear. Basically I have eight EditTexts and methods to check if they're empty, set values and get values. Since each method accesses all the EditTexts it seemed helpful to access them in a loop using their ids instead of using a variable which causes the code to be more verbose. I just had never seen a similar pattern so I was curious if this actually hurt the readability of the code.

Comment: first thing, you yourself mentioned that `getview().findviewbyid()` is a costly operation. but since you are accessing that method multiple times. its cost will turn into x*8. so the answer by shaishav makes sense. create an `edittext` array, initialize them in `onviewcreated()` and use them in a loop whenever you want. this will also elimina the chamce of `getview()` returning null values.

Answer (score 0):

You have already captured some of the nuances in the approaches. Personally, I'd choose code readability over performance in most cases. In your case however, I strongly believe an array approach would fare much better.

```
private EditeText[] roleEditTexts = new EditText[8];
// assign
```

This would also avoid the costly calls to `findViewById()` (if you are calling that code snippet multiple times).

Comment: I'm actually using an array with the EditText ids in the for loop. I'll edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: @apicellaj Okay but, my point is [I suggest to] keep view references themselves in an array because you mentioned you have multiple methods to go through these views. This would quickly add up the calls to `findViewById()` which goes through the ENTIRE view hierarchy to find each view. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the array was an EditText array. That definitely seems a better way to handle it if I don't end up using the variables.